# preg_replace() the same string by increment variable based on occurrences order

Tags: php, regex, string, str-replace

My string:

```
$string = "figno some text and another figno then last figno";
```

**Expected output**

```
1 some text and another 2 then last 3
```

**I tried so far:**

```
preg_match_all("/figno/s",$string,$figmatch);
$figno=0;
for($i=0;$i<count($figmatch[0]);$i++){
    $figno=$figno+1;
    $string=str_replace($figmatch[0][$i],$figno,$string);

}
```

But it replaces all the occurrences at a time. I tried `preg_replace`in the place of `str_replace()` too but same output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use [`preg_replace_callback()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php), so that it calls the anonymous function for every match which you get and then pass the variable `$count` by reference to keep track of the amount of matches, e.g.

```
<?php

    $string = "figno some text and another figno then last figno";
    $count = 1;
    echo preg_replace_callback("/figno/s", function($m)use(&$count){
        return $count++;
    }, $string);

?>
```

output:

```
1 some text and another 2 then last 3
```

Answer (score 1):

Use preg_replace_callback

```
$count = 0;
preg_replace_callback('/figno/', 'rep_count', $string);

function rep_count($matches) {
  global $count;
  return $count++;
}
```